# Doing rspec testing with subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

So I have an app that is heavily dependant on subdomains that are generated with each user.
And what I need is to pass the proper subdomain for each test so I can test the actual function of an action.
so after some looking I found this:

```
  def set_subdomain(subdomain, path)
    URI.join("http://#{subdomain}.lvh.me", path).to_s
  end
```

this basically gives me the full url including the subdomain for each path but, I can't pass that into `get` because it sees it as a path and not a url. I can actually use `visit` but only on feature testing with capybara and I don't want to do that so, what is the alternative to this ?

Comment: What type of test are you writing?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about request specs here. I believe the only way to do this is to pass the full URL to the `get/post/etc`.

```
get root_url(subdomain: "sub")
```